# Google Sign-in crash & error: uiDelegate must either be a |UIViewController|

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google Sign-in to an iOS app but the app crashes on clicking on the Sign-in button with the following error:

```
reason: 'uiDelegate must either be a |UIViewController| or implement the |signIn:presentViewController:| and |signIn:dismissViewController:| methods from |GIDSignInUIDelegate|.'
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I've followed the [sample code from Google's iOS github](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/signin) exactly. I also can't get Google's sample to compile. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great. Most of the SO questions are based on dated code.

Viewcontroller

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn

@objc(ViewController)

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    // Viewcontroller buttons
    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var signOutButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var disconnectButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusText: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

        // Sign in automatically
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

        // Something to do with notifications
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(ViewController.receiveToggleAuthUINotification(_:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"),
                                               object: nil)

        statusText.text = "Initialized Swift App..."
        toggleAuthUi()
    }

    // Sign out tapped
    @IBAction func didTapDisconnect(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().disconnect()
        statusText.text = "Disconnecting"
    }

    // Toggle auth
    func toggleAuthUi() {
        if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {
            signInButton.isHidden = true
            signOutButton.isHidden = false
            disconnectButton.isHidden = false
        } else {
            signInButton.isHidden = false
            signOutButton.isHidden = true
            disconnectButton.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
                                                  name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"),
                                                  object: nil)
    }

    @objc func receiveToggleAuthUINotification(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        if notification.name.rawValue == "ToggleAuthUINotification" {
            self.toggleAuthUi()
            if notification.userInfo != nil {
                guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String:String] else {return}
                self.statusText.text = userInfo["statusText"]!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    // Did Finished Launching
    func application (_ application: UIApplication,
                      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Init Sign in
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "XXXXXXXXX"
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        return true
    }

    // Open URL
    func application (_app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }

    public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(
                name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotificiation"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
        } else {
            // User Stuff
            let userID = user.userID
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken
            let fullName = user.profile.name
            let givenName = user.profile.givenName
            let familyName = user.profile.familyName
            let email = user.profile.email

            NotificationCenter.default.post(
                name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"),
                object: nil,
                userInfo: ["statusText": "Signed in user:\n\(fullName)"])
        }
    }

    public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        // Disconnect the user
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ToggleAuthUINotification"),
            object: nil,
            userInfo: ["statusText": "User has disconnect."])
    }

}
```

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: I never managed to solve it unfortunately.

Comment: The below answer by Nicolay is correct. You need to implement `GIDSignInUIDelegate` with its delegate methods in your view controller presenting the google sign in from a custom login button.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: If using a non-`UIViewController` as a `uiDelegate` - check if Xcode is warning you that "*Instance method [...] nearly matches optional requirement [...]*" and use the Fix-Its. Make sure your functions match the required signature exactly.

---

I had the same error after following the sample code.

In my case the setup was a bit different, so I am not sure if my solution is applicable to your question - but because this StackOverflow answer shows up in Google Search, I thought I'd provide my resolution here for any people stumbling upon it:

I needed a non-`UIVIewController` subclass to be the Google Sign In `uiDelegate`. As the documentation and the error state, this means you need to implement some methods. I had implemented them, so it was strange that things were crashing.

In my case, the issue was that the copy-pasted code from Google's documentation was not exactly matching the Swift function signatures. In fact, I had warnings in Xcode, saying "*Instance method [...] nearly matches optional requirement [...]*". I used the auto Fix-Its by Xcode (it was stuff such as `Error` instead of `NSError`, or `_` before a function's argument.)

Then it all worked.